# Redirect to url by nodejs

Tags: node.js

i tried to receive get request and redirect the user to another url
but the url not changing

```
const success_url = 'https://site.online/success'
const query = '?order_id=123123&data=abc'

res.status(301).redirect(`${success_url}${query}`);

// the output must be https://site.online/success?order_id=123123&data=abc
// but i get http://localhost:3000/success?order_id=123123&data=abc

also tried res.redirect(301, `${success_url}${query}`);
```

How i can change localhost:3000 to the domain of the target url

Answer (score 0):

You want to use [.redirect(code, url)](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.redirect).

```js
res.redirect(301, `${success_url}${query}`);
```

Comment: same result 
when i go to http://localhost:3000/ping/result?success=true&order=55795680
i get redirect to http://localhost:3000/success?success=true&order=55795680
while i need to go to http://site.online/success?success=true&order=55795680

Comment: hi, the content of the screen gets redirected but the url remains the same. Why is that?